# How do I get a testnet wallet in Monero GUI?

Tags: testnet, wallet

I just need a testnet wallet. The testnet wallet can be any.
If this is possible I want to access it from XMR GUI Wallet

Answer (score 1):

You can select `Testnet` as network parameter in the wizard (setup) of the GUI (under `Advanced` options). See this part of the Monero GUI guide and corresponding screenshot.

https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#create-a-wallet

In case you choose to use a remote node, make sure to connect to a *testnet* remote node.